# Count rows with specific data only, excluding data if it has another record with different details in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-query-store

I have 3 columns in my table tbl_Result such as: id, Serial and Result, in Serial column data can be duplicate if it has pass and fail results, I want to select the Serial that has Pass only meaning don't include the Serial with fail even it has a pass.

[as you can see in my data Serial A1 and A5 has pass and fail results I don't want to include that in my select query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnEZC.jpg)

I tried this code below but I'm still selecting the A1 and A5 Serial,
the total records I am expecting should be 8 only.

```
Select Serial, Result from tbl_Result where Result='pass' and Result not in('fail')
group by Serial, Result
having count(Serial)<2
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `COUNT( CASE WHEN Result = 'pass' THEN 1 END ) AS FilteredCount`

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: And please show both sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need conditional aggregation. You are also grouping by too many columns.

```sql
SELECT
  Serial
FROM tbl_Result
GROUP BY
  Serial
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Result = 'Fail' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```